# Custom view on admin site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like to have a custom view on a model admin.

Current behavior:

When i click on Model object(1) it takes me to `site/app_label/1/change`,
This leads to edit of the object with its inlines.

What I want to achieve:

when i click on a object should redirect to `site/app_label/1` it should show a list view of its inlines (Not a editable list) i will put a separate button which will lead to `site/app_label/1/change`

I want this list view to be similar to Django default style listing.

My two models are:

```
class RunConfig(models.Model):
    config_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,null=False, unique=True )


class Jobs(models.Model):
    config_name     = models.ForeignKey('RunConfig',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    job_name        = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True, )
    parameters      = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True, )
    exec_order      = models.IntegerField(help_text="Execution Order")
```

admin.py

```
class JobsInline(SortableInlineAdminMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    model = Jobs
    extra = 1


class RunConfigAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display  = ('config_name',)
```

What I have tried till now:

My plan was to override the changelist template but that did not work as it started to complain about no reverse match found for app_list

in admin.py added custom url

```
def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(RunConfigAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = [

            url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',  self.admin_site.admin_view(RunConfigDetailView.as_view(), cacheable=True), name='rc-detail'),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls
```

created a detailed view on views.py i was expecting it wil be easier to use the `context['job']` to achive the result but I failed :(

```
class RunConfigDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = RunConfig
    context_object_name = 'rc_detail'


    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(RunConfigDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['opts']  = self.model._meta
        context['jobs'] = Jobs.objects.filter(config_name=self.object.id)

        return context
```